# how to post on ispconfig?

Tags: php, web, debian, ispconfig

When I publish my site on ispconfig I have a problem while it works locally and on virtualmin, here is the error:

```
[Wed Sep 16 15:20:22.111023 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 20093] [client 77.153.22.28:33676] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\\Common\\Persistence\\Mapping\\MappingException' with message 'The class 'IBoutiq3\\Entity\\Utilisateur' was not found in the chain configured namespaces IBoutiq3/var/www/clients/client1/web15/web\\Entity' in /var/www/clients/client1/web15/web/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:37
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/clients/client1/web15/web/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php(112): Doctrine\\Common\\Persistence\\Mapping\\MappingException::classNotFoundInNamespaces('IBoutiq3\\\\Entity...', Array)
#1 /var/www/clients/client1/web15/web/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(151): Doctrine\\Common\\Persistence\\Mapping\\Driver\\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass('IBoutiq3\\\\Entity...', Object(Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\ClassMetadata))\n#2 /var/www/clients/client1/web15/web/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractCl...
```

Comment: the message said your site can't found some class, did you upload or launch composer for have the vendor directory ? And it's present on your webserver ?

Comment: The classes and the vendors file is present.
`code`
/var/www/cuisinedubienetre.fr/web# ls
AjaxController.php  btncommande.html.twig  cli-config.php   composer.lock  console     error   FlashObject  index.php  pimple.json  robots.txt     Twig    Xtras
Assets      c1      CollectionProduit.php  composer.phar  Controller  favicon.ico  image.php    Paiement   Plugins      sitemap-1.xml  vendor
bootstrap.php     Classes     composer.json   Config  Entity      Fichiers   Images       PDF   robots       stats       View `code`

Comment: so you have problem with your web application path in ispconfig because the code search the file here : IBoutiq3/var/www/clients/client1/web15/web\